# Terraform security group and security group rule modules

Tags: terraform

I have this object of security group. Wondering if there's a way to create security groups and their rule corresponding to their security group id

```
security_group = {
security_group_1 = { 
  description : "description 1"
  sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
  },
security_group_2 = { 
  description : "description 2"
  sg_rule : 
   - { type: "ingress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
   - { type: "egress".
       from_port: 1433;
       to_port: 1433,
       protocol: "TCP",
       cidr_block: [10.0.0.0/24]
     }
}
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [aws_vpc.example.cidr_block]
  security_group_id = ''
}
```

using these 2 resources
should create 2 security groups and 4 group rules:

- aws_security_group.sg[security_group_1]
- aws_security_group.sg[security_group_2]
- aws_security_group_rule.rule[security_group_1-ingress]
- aws_security_group_rule.rule[security_group_1-egress]
- aws_security_group_rule.rule[security_group_2-ingress]
- aws_security_group_rule.rule[security_group_2-egress]

And make sure in "aws_security_group_rule" "rule" resource it using the correct security_group_id

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the known relationships in configuration and transpose those configurations into loopable structures that resources can then bind to. There are a few ways to do this. The example below uses a list(object) as parent with a list(object) for the children. The variables are projected into flattened `locals` that fit nicely in a resource's `for_each` construct. There are less verbose methods and this may also be easily done using the `count` construct.

Below is just one example and has not been tested.

```
# in variables.tf
variable "security_groups" {
    type = list(object({
    id = string,    
    description  = string,         
    sg_rules = list(object({
        id = string, 
        type = string,   
        from_port = number,
        to_port = number,
        protocol = string,
        cidr_block = list(string)
      }))
    }))
}


# in varfiles/dev.tf
security_groups = [
    {
        id = "security_group_1",
        description = "description 1",              
        sg_rules = [            
            {
                id = "security_group_1-ingress",
                type = "ingress",
                from_port = 1433,
                to_port = 1433,
                protocol = "TCP",
                cidr_block = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
            },                  
            {
                id = "security_group_1-egress"
                type = "egress",
                from_port = 1433,
                to_port = 1433,
                protocol = "TCP",
                cidr_block = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id = "security_group_2",
        description = "description 2",      
        sg_rules = [            
            {
                id = "security_group_2-ingress",
                type = "ingress",
                from_port = 1433,
                to_port = 1433,
                protocol = "TCP",
                cidr_block = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
            },                  
            {
                id = "security_group_2-egress",
                type = "egress",
                from_port = 1433,
                to_port = 1433,
                protocol = "TCP",
                cidr_block = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
            }
        ]
    }

]

# in locals.tf
locals {
    
    security_groups_flattened = flatten([
        for x, sg in var.security_groups : {
            security_group_id = sg.id
            name = "allow_tls",
            description = sg.description                
        }
    ])

    security_groups_rules_flattened = flatten([
        for x, sg in var.security_groups : [
            for y, sgr in sg.sg_rules : {      
                security_group_id = sg.id
                security_group_rule_id = sgr.id
                type = sgr.type
                from_port = sgr.from_port
                to_port = sgr.to_port
                protocol = sgr.protocol
                cidr_blocks = sgr.cidr_block
            }
        ]
    ])
}

# in resources

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {  
  for_each = { for security_group in local.security_groups_flattened : security_group.security_group_id => security_group }       
  
  name = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule" {
  for_each = { for security_groups_rule in local.security_groups_rules_flattened : security_groups_rule.security_group_rule_id => security_groups_rule }

  type              = each.value.type
  from_port         = each.value.from_port
  to_port           = each.value.to_port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  cidr_blocks       = each.value.cidr_blocks
  security_group_id = 
  aws_security_group.sg[each.value.security_group_id].endpoint_arn
}
```